# Canvas context.font use self hosted web fonts

Tags: css, html5-canvas, webfonts

I am wondering if there is a way to self-hosted web fonts that are used by Canvas context.font. Please reference my code below with how I have tried to implement this. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
    @font-face
    {
        font-family:arial;
        src:url("fonts/arial.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: avant_garde;
        src:url("fonts/avant_garde.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: times_new_roman;
        src:url("fonts/times_new_roman.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: garamond;
        src:url("fonts/garamond.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: trajan_pro;
        src:url("fonts/trajan_pro.otf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: albertus_lt;
        src:url("fonts/albertus_lt.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: monotrype_corsiva;
        src:url("fonts/monotrype_corsiva.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: lucida_causal;
        src:url("fonts/lucida_causal.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: benguait_gothic_bk;
        src:url("fonts/benguait_gothic_bk.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: engravers_gothic;
        src:url("fonts/engravers_gothic.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: futura_bk;
        src:url("fonts/futura_bk.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: eurostile;
        src:url("fonts/eurostile.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: copper_lt;
        src:url("fonts/copper_lt.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: korinna;
        src:url("fonts/korinna.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: souviner;
        src:url("fonts/souviner.ttf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: tekton_pro_blend;
        src:url("fonts/tekton_pro_blend.otf");
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: garamond_drop_caps;
        src:url("fonts/garamond_drop_caps.ttf");
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com//jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundedRect = function (x, y, width, height, radius)
  {
   this.save();
   this.translate(x, y);
   this.moveTo(width / 2,0);
   this.arcTo(width,0,width,height, Math.min(height / 2, radius));
   this.arcTo(width, height, 0, height, Math.min(width / 2, radius));
   this.arcTo(0, height, 0, 0, Math.min(height / 2, radius));
   this.arcTo(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.min(width / 2, radius));
   this.lineTo(width / 2,0);
   this.restore();
 }

  $(function() {
    var canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0];
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.beginPath();
    context.roundedRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0);
    context.lineWidth=2;
    context.strokeStyle="#000000";
    context.stroke();

    $('#nametag').bind('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
    $('.line1').bind('click', updateCanvas);
    $('.line2').bind('click', updateCanvas);
    $('.line3').bind('click', updateCanvas);

    function updateCanvas() {
      var maxWidth = canvas.width;
      var styling = $('.style').val();
      console.log(styling);
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height,0);

      if (styling =='Round') {
        context.beginPath();
        context.roundedRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 25);
        context.lineWidth=2;
        context.strokeStyle="#000000";
        context.stroke();
      } else {
        context.beginPath();
        context.roundedRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0);
        context.stroke();
      }

      //Style Font
      if($('.font').val() == 'arial'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "arial");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'avantgarde'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "avant_garde");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'timesnewroman'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "times_new_roman");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'garamond'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "garamond");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'trajanpro'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "trajan_pro");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'albertuslt'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "albertus_lt");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'monotypecorsiva'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "monotrype_corsiva");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'lucidacasual'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "lucida_causal");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'benguaitgothicbk'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "benguait_gothic_bk");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'engraversgothic'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "engravers_gothic");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'futurabk'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "futura_bk");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'eurostile'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "eurostile");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'cooperlt'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "copper_lt");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'garamonddropcaps'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "garamond_drop_caps");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'korinna'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "korinna");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'souvinerlt'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "souviner");
      } else if($('.font').val() == 'tektonproblend'){
        $('#textEntry1, #textEntry2, #textEntry3').css("font-family", "tekton_pro_blend");
      }

      context.textAlign = "center";

      context.fillText($('.line1').val(), canvas.width * 0.5, 70, maxWidth);
      context.fillText($('.line2').val(), canvas.width * 0.5, 90, maxWidth);
      context.fillText($('.line3').val(), canvas.width * 0.5, 120, maxWidth);

    }
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="font-family: arial">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: avant_garde">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: times_new_roman">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: garamond">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: trajan_pro">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: albertus_lt">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: monotrype_corsiva">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: lucida_causal">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: benguait_gothic_bk">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: engravers_gothic">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: futura_bk">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: eurostile">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: copper_lt">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: korinna">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: souviner">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: tekton_pro_blend">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="font-family: garamond_drop_caps">&nbsp;</div>
  <form action="" method="POST" id="nametag" class="nametag">
    <b>Name Tag</b><br>
    <div id="canvas-container">
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="style">
      <label>Style:</label>
      <select class="style" name="style" style="width:250px;">
        <option></option>
        <option>Round</option>
        <option>Square</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <label for="font">Font: </label>
      <select name="font" class="font" id="font">
        <option></option>
        <option value="arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="avantgarde">Avant Garde</option>
        <option value="timesnewroman">Times New Roman</option>
        <option value="garamond">Garamond</option>
        <option value="trajanpro">Trajan Pro</option>
        <option value="albertuslt">Albertus Lt</option>
        <option value="monotypecorsiva">Monotype Corsiva</option>
        <option value="lucidacasual">Lucida Casual</option>
        <option value="benguaitgothicbk">Benguait Gothic Bk</option>
        <option value="engraversgothic">Engravers Gothic</option>
        <option value="futurabk">Futura Bk</option>
        <option value="eurostile">Eurostile</option>
        <option value="cooperlt">Cooper Lt</option>
        <option value="garamonddropcaps">Garamond Drop Caps</option>
        <option value="korinna">Korinna</option>
        <option value="souvinerlt">Souviner Lt</option>
        <option value="tektonproblend">Tekton Pro Blend</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="line1">
      <label>Line1:</label>
      <input type="text" class='line1' name="line1" style="width:250px;" maxlength="50"/>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="line2">
      <label>Line2:</label>
      <input type="text" class='line2' name="line2" style="width:250px;" maxlength="50"/>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="line3">
      <label>Line3:</label>
      <input type="text" class='line3' name="line3" style="width:250px;" maxlength="50"/>
    </div>
    <br>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```